# How to decorate Controller/Actions with attribute from Client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes

Assume i have several **Controllers** and **Actions** in my **WebAPI**. Also i have **custom attribute** that i want to **apply** in some of my Controllers or Actions. Generally to do that, i will decorate desired Controller or their Actions with that attribute.

**My question is:** *is there any way in MVC 5 that let me do the decoration from UI side* e.g. to **choose between** certain *attributes* that can be applied to certain *controllers* or to their *actions* from **browser ?**

I know i can use **Swagger/Swashbuckle** to iterate through all of my controllers and expose them to the user. Also, i already have written my custom attribute.

Can anyone point me to any direction that will help me to solve this problem ?

I guess there can be a solution that involving overriding **BaseController** in such a way that every newly created controller that derived BaseController to be decorated with my custom attribute.

Comment: Do you need to enable/disable your custom attribute per request? or globally, for all requests.

Comment: Both, but mostly globally

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the solution to solve this that provided out of the box.
But it still could be solved.

I'm seeing to possible solutions:

**First** one is to let all your filter decide if it should be applied or skipped.
This approach is messy. It will require you to apply all filters at the start and in this case all filters will be called always (at least for check the condition).

**Second** one is to implement your own FilterProvider which will return the collection of applied filters (e.g. by some conditions) ([here is an article with a simple example](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/)).
I would recommend this approach, because it looks more clear and it will require only one call per request to determine which filters should be applied/called.

Anyway, both approached will require some UI page for configuring all these filters and you need to store all these configs somewhere (create at least three DB tables: Controller, Action and Filter). And this stored information will be used to make all this work.

I hope it will help.